# How to copy text file from document directory in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

Hello i am trying to copy text file from document directory into folder name `Temp` that located in document directory.

Here is some of code i tried and didn't work.

```
self.fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *documentsDirectoryToTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Temp/",[paths objectAtIndex:0]];

        NSString *txtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",tblGetNameToMove.textLabel.text]];

        [self.fileManager copyItemAtPath:txtPath toPath:documentsDirectoryToTemp error:&error];
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution. I need to add directory and also name of file and extension.

Here is codes.

```
self.fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *txtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",tblGetNameToMove.textLabel.text]];

        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Temp/%@.txt",documentsDirectory,tblGetNameToMove.textLabel.text];

        [self.fileManager copyItemAtPath:txtPath toPath:fileName error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for this :

1. First try to print all the path like documentsDirectoryToTempn and txtPath whether it is correct or not .
2. The second thing is make use that error variable  :

   if(error)
   {
     NSLog("Error while coping :%@",[error localizedDiscription]);
   }

   so you can track exact problem .